Is the spinning Cosmic String spacetime totally vicious?
The spacetime $(M,g)$ is given locally at each point by the metric:
$$g= -(dt + a \, d \phi)^2 + d\rho^2 + \kappa^2 \rho^2 \, d\phi^2 + dz^2 \ \text{where} \ \ a > 0$$
This is the spacetime of a spinning Cosmic String.
A spacetime is called totally vicious if and only if a closed timelike curve passes through each point of it.
Is this spacetime totally vicious?

Is this homework? What have you tried to answer this question yourself?

I have not thought about it not even 1 minute. It's not a homework. I guess it must be written in the Minkowski format by a change of coordinate, and then checked if CTCs can be deformed to pass through any arbitrary point of the manifold. @TimRias
